# How to aggregate based on one label value, but preserve the other label values?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I want to take the min of a metric based on one label, but perserve the other labels so I can extract them later.

Suppose I have these metrics:

```
Metric{label1="1",label2="2"}  0
Metric{label1="1",label2="3"}  1
Metric{label1="2",label2="2"}  10
Metric{label1="2",label2="3"}  100
```

If I do

```
min(Metric)by(label1)
```

I get the correct results:

```
{label1="1"} 0
{label1="2"}  10
```

but I lose the label2, which I would like to extract later.

Is there a way to min by label1, while still preserving label2 in the result?

What I want the output of my aggregation to be:

```
Metric{label1="1",label2="2"}  0
Metric{label1="2",label2="2"}  10
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you want `bottomk by(label1)(1, Metric)`

Comment: Is there a way to use min to preserve the label? My problem with bottomk is that it yields multiple results if multiple label1 were the min at some point in the chosen time frame. I would like to have a graph of the min value while preserving the label to inform the user which label2 currently has the lowest value. With bottomk I get a line for each variable that had been the min at least once. Since I am interested in the progress, I cannot use type instant.
Thank you!